# basic async await javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've got this very basic async await which I believe is not running correctly:

```
  const ex = {
    people: () => {console.log('people')},
    places: () => {console.log('places')}
  }


  async function example() {
    try {
      const people = await ex.people()
      const places = await ex.places()
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  example().then(console.log('last'))
```

output:

```
people
last
places
```

Shouldn't this be outputting 'people, places, last'?

Comment: Your `people` and `places` functions do not return Promises. Is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had tried this but still didn't seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this code snippet is pretty much ok!
The only thing missing here it's that promises returns functions.

So .then should be like this:

```
example().then(() => console.log('last'))
```

Hope it works for you!

Edit:

As @gyre said, `ex.people` and `ex.places` should return promises in order to work correctly

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/8e9jjmv4/1/)